# TCP chat client/server won't work off localhost

Tags: c#, windows, chat, server

I am currently learning to program a chat room application that uses a server. So far everything works fine if I run the server and multiple instances of the application on a single machine. When I try to run the server on one machine and the actual chat application from another, I get an exception that reads "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (Ipaddress)(port)"

Server side code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChatAppServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Hashtable ClientList = new Hashtable(); 
        const int PORT = 321;
        string localIp;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            TcpListener sckServer = new TcpListener(PORT);
            TcpClient sckClient = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            sckServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Chat Server is now Running ....");
            counter = 0;
            //Parser myParser = new Parser();
            while (true)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
                sckClient = sckServer.AcceptTcpClient();

                string clientData = "";
                byte[] recieveData = new byte[10025]; 

                NetworkStream netStream = sckClient.GetStream();
                netStream.Read(recieveData, 0, (int)sckClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                clientData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveData);
                clientData = clientData.Substring(0, clientData.IndexOf("$"));

                ClientList.Add(clientData, sckClient);

                Broadcast(clientData + " joined the chat", clientData, false);

                Console.WriteLine(clientData + " connected to the chat");
                handleClient client = new handleClient();
                client.ClientStart(sckClient, clientData, ClientList);
            }
            sckClient.Close();
            sckServer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void Broadcast(string msg, string userName, bool flag)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in ClientList)
            {
                TcpClient sckBroadcast;
                sckBroadcast = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
                NetworkStream broadcastStream = sckBroadcast.GetStream();
                Byte[] broadcastData = null;

                if (flag == true)
                {
                    broadcastData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ": " + msg);
                }
                else 
                {
                    broadcastData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                }
                broadcastStream.Write(broadcastData, 0, broadcastData.Length);
                broadcastStream.Flush();
            }
        }

        public class handleClient
        {
            TcpClient sckClient;
            string clId;
            Hashtable ClientList;

            public void ClientStart(TcpClient inSckClient, string clientId, Hashtable clist) {
                this.sckClient = inSckClient;
                this.clId = clientId;
                this.ClientList = clist;
                Thread ctThread = new Thread(runChat);
                ctThread.Start();
            }
            private void runChat() {
                int requestCount = 0;
                byte[] recieveData = new byte[10025];
                string clientData = "";
                string rCount = null;

                while ((true))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        requestCount += 1;
                        NetworkStream netStream = sckClient.GetStream();
                        netStream.Read(recieveData, 0, (int)sckClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        clientData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveData);
                        clientData = clientData.Substring(0, clientData.IndexOf("$"));
                        Console.WriteLine(clId + " : " + clientData);
                        rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                        Program.Broadcast(clientData, clId, true);


                    }
                    catch(Exception ex) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Chat room application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Need for the application
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;


namespace ChatApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient sckClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream svrStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string recieveData = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recieveData = "Connected to Server";
            msg();
            int serverPort = Convert.ToInt32(txtServerPort.Text);
            sckClient.Connect(txtServerIp.Text, serverPort);
            svrStream = sckClient.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtUserName.Text + "$");
            svrStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            svrStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(MessageCallBack);
            btnSend.Enabled = true;
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;
            txtUserName.Enabled = false;
            txtServerIp.Enabled = false;
            txtServerPort.Enabled = false;
            ctThread.Start();

        }

        private void MessageCallBack()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                svrStream = sckClient.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = sckClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
                svrStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                recieveData = "" + returnData;
                msg();
            }
        }
        //function to display data strings 
        private void msg()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
            }
            else
            {
                lstMessage.Items.Add(recieveData);
            }
        }



        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text + "$");
            svrStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            svrStream.Flush();
            txtMessage.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: Correct IP? Firewalls off? Are you only *listening* on "localhost"?

Comment: What is the IP you are connecting to and the port? Welcome to StackOverflow by the way! This sounds like an issue with one of your computers firewalls, or the incorrect IP (Using a machine other than your computer, but on the local network needs a 192.168.0.X IP, usually)

Comment: is the port already in use on the remote server

Comment: @MethodMan it would be a different error message if the port was already in use.

Comment: i changed some code  and now i get the error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it... the line i changed was   TcpListener sckServer = new TcpListener(PORT);                           to                                                                                               TcpListener sckServer = new TcpListener("127.0.0.1", PORT);

Answer (score 0):

I have two troubles with your code :

- Do not use `.ReceiveBufferSize` value because it's a different value of your byte array length. And you can have an index out of range exception.
- You have a problem of concurrency in the server side. More than 1 thread try to access to the `ClientList` and this collection is **not thread-safe**.

To resolve this, you can use the `lock` keyword

```
private static object _lock = new object();
//...
lock (_lock)
{
     ClientList.Add(clientData, sckClient);
}

lock (_lock)
{
     Broadcast(clientData + " joined the chat", clientData, false);
}
//...
lock (_lock)
{
     Program.Broadcast(clientData, clId, true);

}
```

As you're a beginner, i would give you some tips.

- Try to use the asynchronous network functions (better than raw threads), [an example there](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16916/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-TCP-Sockets).
- There is a lot of tutorials about safety with severals connections in C# (with some thing else, better, than the `lock` keyword).